# Error SonarCloud : "This class has 6 parents which is greater than 5 authorized."

Tags: java, class, error-handling, sonarcloud

My test in sonarcloud reports this error that I have never found anywhere.

```html
public class PngjPrematureEnding extends PngjInputException {

    public PngjPrematureEnding(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

How should I redefine this class?

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing your class hierarchy. The complaint is about you class hierarchy. Maybe you should favor composition over inheritance. If you want to stick with your class hierarchy, configure sonar's threshold higher.